# Is there a practical way to parallelize the construction of a Huffman tree, given the complete set of frequencies?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, huffman-code

I'm working on a small Java program that compresses text files using Huffman coding and I'm just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction regarding the parallelization of Huffman tree construction.

Editing to add that I've done some research but there doesn't appear to be much out there on parallelizing Huffman trees and what I have found is somewhat archaic or just beyond my understanding, mathematically.

Comment: Please add any code you have tried and what specifically is not working.  Huffman tree coding is something you would do in a programming course.  is this for college/programming school or something you are trying to do on your own/

Comment: Had to give you a negative as I found a completely downloadable program which implements Huffman in a multi thread environment.  However I believe this is a school project and you will need to do the work to find it :-)

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You want to compute the Huffman tree (why would that need to be parallel?) or encode a file according to a pre-computed Huffman encoding?  If the latter, one of your biggest problems will be that files are read more or less sequentially from disk.

Comment: @DavidColer Yes, this is for a homework assignment. I'm trying to understand, conceptually, how to parallelize tree construction, not just copy code I found online.

Comment: @IraBaxter One of the requirements for the assignment that this program is based off of is to speed up the Huffman tree construction using multiple threads. It's not that I think this is a practical idea in the first place, rather it's meant to challenge us to build trees in parallel. So to answer your question, it is the former case.

Comment: To build the Huffman tree, you first need statistical counts of occurrences of the leaves.  If the leaves are going to be characters (or substrings) that are derived from the file, you are going to be rate limited to how fast you can read the file *just to collect the statistics*.   If you understand this and the assignment insists on building the tree in parallel anyway, then its just homework and you're going to a have a good time.  Hope the prof discusses this in class.

Answer (score 0):

You can google it and find ways to do it. (Note that "beyond your understanding" is a temporary state resolved by studying the literature.) However in practice there is no need to. The generation of the Huffman codes is generally a tiny fraction of the compression time.

Have you profiled your code to see if you're even asking the right question?